# Transform small Arduino protoboard project in a final solution

Tags: arduino, production, protoboard

I am collecting data on consumption and solar production and I centralize it in a Raspberry with Openhab.
Now I want to connect to Smart Grid Ready and/or Power Control of a Panasonic Aquarea aerothermal unit.

I will use mainly an Arduino and some already done modules like (two relays module, PWM to 10v module, ethernet module and possibly some LEDs or little LCD). As I've very little experience on electronics I will try to go for already done modules.

I will start with a protoboard, but now that I plan to buy all the components I'm considering what's the best way to transform it into a final solution, to put in the machine room when I test it.

There are premade special boxes where I can fit what I will need and have outputs for ethernet, power,...?
In case I've to use only already done modules I suppose that a simple box and wire will be enough, but If I need to use some electrical components what's the easiest way to go, a stripboard?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you are looking for some sort of "universal enclosure" ?

In most cases, for this sort of design people would use an aluminium or plastic enclosure with a plain front panel to which you will drill the hole and file them to fit your needs or have it CNC / Laser cut.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use plastic enclosure that has open top / bottom to which you can put your connector and this doesn't need extra work, but also does not protect as well as the aluminium custom made one: